# Android ProgressBar Kotlin - show until some code is completed

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar, android-progressbar

What is the easiest way **in Kotlin** to show Android ProgressBar covering the whole app untill some code is finished (for example adding some data to database)?

The ProgressBar can be shown using this snippet:

```
val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait")
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...")
progressDialog.show()
```

But how can I easily make it visible until the task is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out!

First of all, declare the ProgressBar this way at the top of any class:

```
lateinit var progressDialog: ProgressDialog
```

Then, start it this way:

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait")
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...")
progressDialog.setCancelable(false) // blocks UI interaction 
progressDialog.show()
```

The above code will block UI until your code completes. When it finishes, just hide the progressBar:

```
progressDialog.hide()
```

Simple, neat and fine! Enjoy! :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you are use jetpack compose;

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            yourTheme{
                MainScreenView()
            }
        }
    }
```

```
@Composable
fun MainScreenView(){

    var isLoading by remember {
        mutableStateOf(yourViewModel.isLoading.value)
    }

    if(isLoading){
      //Loading View
    }else{
      //Your Actual View
    }
}
```

```
class YourViewModel (
    private val useCases: UseCases
): ViewModel() {

   var isLoading = mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

   fun exampleAddDataToDatabase(data: Data){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            useCases.addDataToDatabase(data).collect{ response ->
                when(response){
                    is Response.Loading -> {isLoading.value = true}
                    is Response.Success -> {isLoading.value = false}
                    is Response.Error -> {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other simpler solution?